# Altering default desktop background setting?

Tags: 14.04, settings

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 and am very pleased. I do have a question
that probably has a simple answer.
  When setting an image as the desktop background, the default setting for desktop background is 'zoom'. Is there a way to change that default setting
to 'scale' rather than 'zoom'? Images today are mostly larger than most screen's real estate (although that may not be true for 24" monitors).
  If this is possible, I imagine that some file can be altered to set the default setting of choice.
  Any help would be greatly appreciated Craig

Comment: AFAIK ubuntu zooms out too, but only as far as no black borders are visible. Otherwise it ma be a bug.

Comment: Altering default option ? Maybe not.  But you can alter the current wallpaper scaling through System Settings.

Comment: this is a great question and surely there is a simple setting in a file somewhere. I'd like to know too!